# Why can't I use the pluralize method in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have just come to know that I can't use the method 'pluralize' in the rails console or IRB. Is there anything I don't understand about this?

```
2.3.0 :001 > pluralize
NameError: undefined local variable or method `pluralize' for main:Object
```

It gets interpreted well when it's used in the ruby or view file. Why can't I use it in the rails console?

Comment: So you are trying to pluralize _what_? `main`?

Comment: @mudasobwa: i thought (like you) that pluralize is a method on strings. But it isn't :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev geez...

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it is, in fact, [a method on strings](http://apidock.com/rails/String/pluralize). So `"poop".pluralize` yields "poops".

Comment: @mmichael: huh. First my memory failed me, then my googling. I'm gonna quit internet now.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev been there my friend, been there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `pluralize` method used in Rails views is defined in `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`. To use it in rails console you need to include it

```
$ rails console
2.3.3 :008 > include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
2.3.3 :009 > pluralize 2, 'man'
=> "2 men"
```

or call them through the helper variable

```
$ rails console
2.3.3 :0010 > helper.pluralize(2, 'man')
=> "2 men"
```

Answer (score 3):

It should become clear by looking at the documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize

`pluralize` is defined on `TextHelper`, which means that it is available to your helps and views through ActionView.

You can however use it in rails console like this:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.pluralize(...)
```

Or by including `TextHelper`:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

Answer (score 2):

> It gets interpreted well when it's used in the ruby or view file. Why can't I use it in the rails console?

Because it was meant to be used from views, not from console (by being defined as [an action view helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize)).

But not all hope is lost. You *can* access helper methods in console!

```
helper.pluralize(...)
```